is double checked locking implementation in go valid
This is another don't be smart GO question. of course there is once primitive and that could be used, but this is purely for discussion purposes.
type impl struct {
    fLock         *sync.Mutex
    fValue        TValue
    fGetValueFunc XXXX
}

    var err basic.Error = nil
    lock := impl.fLock

    if lock != nil { // RACE
        lock.Lock()
        defer lock.Unlock()

        if impl.fLock != nil {
            impl.fValue, err = impl.fGetValueFunc()

            if err == nil {
                impl.fGetValueFunc = nil
                impl.fLock = nil // RACE CHECK Complains
            }
        }
    }

the race check complains about the concurrent access. But I am assuming since this is merely an address and it has been assured that the access to machine word is guaranteed to be atomic.
is this double check locking still valid despite the race checking complaining?

Nothing is valid with a race condition. If you need atomic access, use the atomic package.

that is absolutely true, but I want to  know some details

What details are you looking for? If you're not going to follow the spec, you need to be certain that your compiler, architecture and runtime all work exactly as you assume and won't copy/reorder/fail any of the unsynchronized access. If you use the atomic package then it's done for you. (and you can see this same pattern in the sync.Once implementation)

but there aren't much possibilities within these two statements  lock := impl.fLock if lock != nil are there ? I thought these instructions have dependencies

I still don't understand what you are looking for as an answer. Is the algorithm correct, yes it looks correct. Is this valid Go, no, that's why you get an error. Will it probably work, yes, but it's also valid for the runtime to report the race and abort execution.

What the race detector is doing:
With the race detector the compiler instruments all memory accesses with code that records when and how the memory was accessed, while the runtime library watches for unsynchronized accesses to shared variables.
So the race detector is looking for access to shared variables that are not protected by some synchronization (i.e. mutex, channel, etc).

    lock := impl.fLock // create a new var with the same pointer value

    if lock != nil { // READ the value of that pointer (outside synchronization)
        lock.Lock()
        defer lock.Unlock()

                // trimmed
                impl.fLock = nil // Write the value of that pointer (inside synchronization)


The race detector doesn't know the meaning of your code. But you can reasonably assume that all race warnings should be fixed (you don't want to get into the habit of ignoring them).
It's hard to say for sure what the behavior of your program will be without seeing the broader context of the code. For example; is lock ever changed, where is the concurrency, etc.
What we know from your example:
What we do know is :

lock and impl.fLock start out as two pointers to the same mutex at some memory address, say: 0xc0000ac040
assuming lock is never reassigned that mutex is locked at lock.Lock()
impl.fLock = nil doesn't change the mutex, it just changes this pointer from 0xc0000ac040 to 0x0 (nil), the value of lock would remain as 0xc0000ac040

We don't know where impl.fLock is assigned (or worse, reassigned)

If impl.fLock is reassigned, then it's possible that we have two independent mutexes, one at the original address 0xc0000ac040 and one at some new address, say; 0xc000104040
If we have two mutexes, then lock.Lock() is no longer protecting the following block:

        if impl.fLock != nil {
            // it's possible that some concurrent impl.fGetValueFunc = nil
            // gets scheduled between the nil check and the below line, so
            // impl.fGetValueFunc would panic
            impl.fValue, err = impl.fGetValueFunc()

            if err == nil {
                impl.fGetValueFunc = nil

